# BigQuery Есть ли возможность batch-обновлений данных в таблице

Tags: sql, bigquery

Существует таблица в BigQuery куда выгружаются агрегированные данные по пользователям, и через время эти данные изменяются, и необходимо сделать апдейт. DML запросы очень ограниченны. Есть ли возможность выгружать данные батчем, но чтобы данные не повторно записывались, а изменялись по какому-то primary-key

Comment: Если верить документации https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax, то и INSERT, и UPDATE там имеется. Выгружаете свежие данные, требующие именно обновления, в другую таблицу, требующие вставки - в третью, потом одним запросом делаете обновление, вторым вставку, и прибиваете ненужные таблицы с пополнением. Имея у себя "старое" и "новое" состояния данных, подготовить две выгрузки не так уж и сложно.

Comment: Благодарю. Думал может есть более удобный "прямой" способ.